# Filtrar elementos pelo maior atributo

Tags: javascript

```
[
  {x:'Pedro', y:2},
  {x:'Lucas', y:3},
  {x:'Pedro', y:4}
]
```

Qual seria a melhor de filtrar que se repetem no valor de X, permanecendo o que tiver maior valor em Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solução com `sort` e `filter`

Uma solução bem compacta passa por utilizar [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) para ordenar os valores todos por nome e `y`, ficando os de maior `y` primeiro.

Depois utiliza [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para filtrar de forma a que sempre que apanha um elemento repetido ao anterior, descarta-o. Isto funciona porque devido à ordenação, o elemento que quer manter dos repetidos é sempre o primeiro.

Implementação:

```js
let pessoas = [
  {x:'Pedro', y:2},
  {x:'Lucas', y:3},
  {x:'Pedro', y:4}
];

pessoas.sort((p1,p2) => p1.x === p2.x ? p2.y - p1.y : p1.x.localeCompare(p2.x));
let filtradas = pessoas.filter((el, idx) => idx === 0 || pessoas[idx - 1].x !== el.x);

console.log(filtradas);
```

No `sort`, quando os nomes são iguais com `p1.x === p2.x` faz a comparação e devolve o que tem maior `y` com `p2.y - p1.y`. Quando são diferentes usa a comparação de nomes através do [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

No `filter` mantem o valor se for o primeiro com `idx === 0`, ou se o nome for diferente do anterior: `pessoas[idx - 1].x !== el.x`.

### Solução com `for` clássico e `findIndex`

Também pode optar por uma solução tradicional com um `for` clássico e adicionar se não existir ou substituir a que já existe se tiver um `y` menor:

```js
let pessoas = [
  {x:'Pedro', y:2},
  {x:'Lucas', y:3},
  {x:'Pedro', y:4}
];

let filtradas = [];
for (let i = 0; i < pessoas.length; ++i){
   let posPessoa = filtradas.findIndex(p => pessoas[i].x === p.x);
   if (posPessoa === -1){ //não existe
      filtradas.push(pessoas[i]); //adiciona
   }
   else if (filtradas[posPessoa].y < pessoas[i].y){ //existe e tem y menor
      filtradas[posPessoa] = pessoas[i]; //substitui pela de y maior
   }
}

console.log(filtradas);
```

Nesta solução a unica função nativa que utilizei foi [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) para descobrir a posição da pessoa com o mesmo nome no array. Esta devolve `-1` caso o elemento não exista no array.

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma forma de fazer:

```
function removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {
    return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
        return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
    });
};

var lista = [
    { x: 'Pedro', y: 2 },
    { x: 'Lucas', y: 3 },
    { x: 'Pedro', y: 4 }
];
var listaX = removeDuplicates(lista, "x");
for (i = 0; i < listaX.length; i++) {
    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, lista.filter(function (e) { return e.x == listaX[i].x; }).map(function (o) { return o.y; }));
    var maxObj = lista.filter(function (e) { return e.x == listaX[i].x && e.y == max; });
    console.log(maxObj);
}
```

Referências: https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/05/removing-duplicate-objects-array-property-name-javascript/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects